# How to populate an HTML field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this script to pick a date in a form:

```
<script src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#datetime1').datetimepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

and here is the form:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
<input type="text" name="date1" id="datetime1" value = "03/14/2012 00:00"/> 
</form>
```

How can I combine the following script with the datepicker script so that the form is automatically populated with today's date which can then be changed?

```
<!--this prints current date-->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
-->
</script>
```

Comment: do you mean to add a default value of today's date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
     var currentTime = new Date()
     var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
     var day = currentTime.getDate()
     var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
     $('#datetime1').val(month + "/" + day + "/" + year).datetimepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this (jQuery) :

```
$('#datetime1').val(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
```

or (JavaScript) :

```
document.getElementById('datetime1').value = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```

instead of

```
document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
```

The second (jQuery) options uses the [.val() method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set a value of a DOM element with the id (`#`) of `datetime1`. And may i suggest [this mozilla JavaScript tutorial as a great place to start learning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you are trying to pre-populate your input with the current day:

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('datetime1').innerHTML = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```

jquery:

```
$('#datetime1').val(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the document ready function for when the page loads and set the value then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#datetime1').val(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
});
```

Hope this helps